# Create SQL SERVER 2008 sql script with WHILE loop that Updates based on array of columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to Put a SQL SELECT into an array? And then execute each update statement in the array in the same SQL script?

```
SELECT 'UPDATE Table_One SET [' + column_name
        + '] = '''' WHERE [' + column_name + '] IS NULL;'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_One';
```

I have a table with 400 columns and wish to execute the above SELECT on EACH column.

I was thinking of a WHILE LOOP and the SELECT would be put into an array of some sort?

Does that functionality exist in SQL or should I just put the SELECT results into a Temp Table?

Comment: One table has 400 columns?

Comment: If `NULL` is not valid, have you considered simply adding a constraint to make the offending columns `NOT NULL` with an additional `DEFAULT` constraint (which would appear to be an empty string `''` in your case)?

Comment: @ThitLwinOo - yes unfortunately, we cannot control what we inherit. <sigh>

Comment: @DMason I may be able to Alter the Table in the same way - using  Alter instead of Update - before I populate the #temp_table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(Max) = ''
SELECT @query = @query + 'UPDATE Table_One SET ' + column_name
        + ' = '''' WHERE ' + column_name + ' = NULL;' + CHAR(13)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_One';

EXEC  sp_executesql  @query
```

Comment: A very nice solution for this type of problem. Thanks!

Comment: I will update my question to reflect `IS NULL;` and not `= NULL;`